# OpenVPN starts from CLI but not using "service" or on boot

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, raspberry-pi

I've set up an OpenVPN server (loosely following [this tutorial](http://readwrite.com/2014/04/10/raspberry-pi-vpn-tutorial-server-secure-web-browsing))

I can start the service using
`sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start`

but if I use
`sudo service openvpn start`
I get the following error:

```
[FAIL] Starting virtual private network daemon: server failed!
```

I assumed that the error was in the `/etc/openvpn/server.conf` file, but it starts ok manually and when it has started I can connect correctly from an off-net client and traffic routes as expected.

When I reboot the server doesn't restart automatically (but I presume this is because of the error above).  That said, this isn't the only service that has an init script that isn't starting correctly, but I'm not sure they're related.

I'm now stumped as to why it doesn't start using the `sudo service openvpn start` form and why it doesn't start on reboot which is a real problem as the machine is often left unattended. Any ideas?

`/etc/init.d/openvpn` as requested:

[20:46 gavin@raspbmc init.d] > sudo cat openvpn

```
#!/bin/sh -e

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          openvpn
# Required-Start:    $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Should-Start:      network-manager
# Should-Stop:       network-manager
# X-Start-Before:    $x-display-manager gdm kdm xdm wdm ldm sdm nodm
# X-Interactive:     true
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Openvpn VPN service
# Description: This script will start OpenVPN tunnels as specified
#              in /etc/default/openvpn and /etc/openvpn/*.conf
### END INIT INFO

# Original version by Robert Leslie
# <rob@mars.org>, edited by iwj and cs
# Modified for openvpn by Alberto Gonzalez Iniesta <agi@inittab.org>
# Modified for restarting / starting / stopping single tunnels by Richard Mueller <mueller@teamix.net>

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

test $DEBIAN_SCRIPT_DEBUG && set -v -x

DAEMON=/usr/sbin/openvpn
DESC="virtual private network daemon"
CONFIG_DIR=/etc/openvpn
test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
test -d $CONFIG_DIR || exit 0

# Source defaults file; edit that file to configure this script.
AUTOSTART="all"
STATUSREFRESH=10
OMIT_SENDSIGS=0
if test -e /etc/default/openvpn ; then
  . /etc/default/openvpn
fi

start_vpn () {
    if grep -q '^[   ]*daemon' $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf ; then
      # daemon already given in config file
      DAEMONARG=
    else
      # need to daemonize
      DAEMONARG="--daemon ovpn-$NAME"
    fi

    if grep -q '^[   ]*status ' $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf ; then
      # status file already given in config file
      STATUSARG=""
    elif test $STATUSREFRESH -eq 0 ; then
      # default status file disabled in /etc/default/openvpn
      STATUSARG=""
    else
      # prepare default status file
      STATUSARG="--status /var/run/openvpn.$NAME.status $STATUSREFRESH"
    fi

    # tun using the "subnet" topology confuses the routing code that wrongly
    # emits ICMP redirects for client to client communications
    SAVED_DEFAULT_SEND_REDIRECTS=0
    if grep -q '^[[:space:]]*dev[[:space:]]*tun' $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf && \
       grep -q '^[[:space:]]*topology[[:space:]]*subnet' $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf ; then
        # When using "client-to-client", OpenVPN routes the traffic itself without
        # involving the TUN/TAP interface so no ICMP redirects are sent
        if ! grep -q '^[[:space:]]*client-to-client' $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf ; then
            sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0 > /dev/null

            # Save the default value for send_redirects before disabling it
            # to make sure the tun device is created with send_redirects disabled
            SAVED_DEFAULT_SEND_REDIRECTS=$(sysctl -n net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects)

            if [ "$SAVED_DEFAULT_SEND_REDIRECTS" -ne 0 ]; then
              sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects=0 > /dev/null
            fi
        fi
    fi

    log_progress_msg "$NAME"
    STATUS=0

    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --oknodo \
        --pidfile /var/run/openvpn.$NAME.pid \
        --exec $DAEMON -- $OPTARGS --writepid /var/run/openvpn.$NAME.pid \
        $DAEMONARG $STATUSARG --cd $CONFIG_DIR \
        --config $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf || STATUS=1

    [ "$OMIT_SENDSIGS" -ne 1 ] || ln -s /var/run/openvpn.$NAME.pid /run/sendsigs.omit.d/openvpn.$NAME.pid

    # Set the back the original default value of send_redirects if it was changed
    if [ "$SAVED_DEFAULT_SEND_REDIRECTS" -ne 0 ]; then
      sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects=$SAVED_DEFAULT_SEND_REDIRECTS > /dev/null
    fi
}
stop_vpn () {
  kill `cat $PIDFILE` || true
  rm -f $PIDFILE
  [ "$OMIT_SENDSIGS" -ne 1 ] || rm -f /run/sendsigs.omit.d/openvpn.$NAME.pid
  rm -f /var/run/openvpn.$NAME.status 2> /dev/null
}

case "$1" in
start)
  log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC"

  # autostart VPNs
  if test -z "$2" ; then
    # check if automatic startup is disabled by AUTOSTART=none
    if test "x$AUTOSTART" = "xnone" -o -z "$AUTOSTART" ; then
      log_warning_msg " Autostart disabled."
      exit 0
    fi
    if test -z "$AUTOSTART" -o "x$AUTOSTART" = "xall" ; then
      # all VPNs shall be started automatically
      for CONFIG in `cd $CONFIG_DIR; ls *.conf 2> /dev/null`; do
        NAME=${CONFIG%%.conf}
        start_vpn
      done
    else
      # start only specified VPNs
      for NAME in $AUTOSTART ; do
        if test -e $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf ; then
          start_vpn
        else
          log_failure_msg "No such VPN: $NAME"
          STATUS=1
        fi
      done
    fi
  #start VPNs from command line
  else
    while shift ; do
      [ -z "$1" ] && break
      if test -e $CONFIG_DIR/$1.conf ; then
        NAME=$1
        start_vpn
      else
       log_failure_msg " No such VPN: $1"
       STATUS=1
      fi
    done
  fi
  log_end_msg ${STATUS:-0}

  ;;
stop)
  log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC"

  if test -z "$2" ; then
    for PIDFILE in `ls /var/run/openvpn.*.pid 2> /dev/null`; do
      NAME=`echo $PIDFILE | cut -c18-`
      NAME=${NAME%%.pid}
      stop_vpn
      log_progress_msg "$NAME"
    done
  else
    while shift ; do
      [ -z "$1" ] && break
      if test -e /var/run/openvpn.$1.pid ; then
        PIDFILE=`ls /var/run/openvpn.$1.pid 2> /dev/null`
        NAME=`echo $PIDFILE | cut -c18-`
        NAME=${NAME%%.pid}
        stop_vpn
        log_progress_msg "$NAME"
      else
        log_failure_msg " (failure: No such VPN is running: $1)"
      fi
    done
  fi
  log_end_msg 0
  ;;
# Only 'reload' running VPNs. New ones will only start with 'start' or 'restart'.
reload|force-reload)
 log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC"
  for PIDFILE in `ls /var/run/openvpn.*.pid 2> /dev/null`; do
    NAME=`echo $PIDFILE | cut -c18-`
    NAME=${NAME%%.pid}
# If openvpn if running under a different user than root we'll need to restart
    if egrep '^[[:blank:]]*user[[:blank:]]' $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
      stop_vpn
      sleep 1
      start_vpn
      log_progress_msg "(restarted)"
    else
      kill -HUP `cat $PIDFILE` || true
    log_progress_msg "$NAME"
    fi
  done
  log_end_msg 0
  ;;

# Only 'soft-restart' running VPNs. New ones will only start with 'start' or 'restart'.
soft-restart)
 log_daemon_msg "$DESC sending SIGUSR1"
  for PIDFILE in `ls /var/run/openvpn.*.pid 2> /dev/null`; do
    NAME=`echo $PIDFILE | cut -c18-`
    NAME=${NAME%%.pid}
    kill -USR1 `cat $PIDFILE` || true
    log_progress_msg "$NAME"
  done
  log_end_msg 0
 ;;

restart)
  shift
  $0 stop ${@}
  sleep 1
  $0 start ${@}
  ;;
cond-restart)
  log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC."
  for PIDFILE in `ls /var/run/openvpn.*.pid 2> /dev/null`; do
    NAME=`echo $PIDFILE | cut -c18-`
    NAME=${NAME%%.pid}
    stop_vpn
    sleep 1
    start_vpn
  done
  log_end_msg 0
  ;;
status)
  GLOBAL_STATUS=0
  if test -z "$2" ; then
    # We want status for all defined VPNs.
    # Returns success if all autostarted VPNs are defined and running
    if test "x$AUTOSTART" = "xnone" ; then
      # Consider it a failure if AUTOSTART=none
      log_warning_msg "No VPN autostarted"
      GLOBAL_STATUS=1
    else
      if ! test -z "$AUTOSTART" -o "x$AUTOSTART" = "xall" ; then
        # Consider it a failure if one of the autostarted VPN is not defined
        for VPN in $AUTOSTART ; do
          if ! test -f $CONFIG_DIR/$VPN.conf ; then
            log_warning_msg "VPN '$VPN' is in AUTOSTART but is not defined"
            GLOBAL_STATUS=1
          fi
        done
      fi
    fi
    for CONFIG in `cd $CONFIG_DIR; ls *.conf 2> /dev/null`; do
      NAME=${CONFIG%%.conf}
      # Is it an autostarted VPN ?
      if test -z "$AUTOSTART" -o "x$AUTOSTART" = "xall" ; then
        AUTOVPN=1
      else
        if test "x$AUTOSTART" = "xnone" ; then
          AUTOVPN=0
        else
          AUTOVPN=0
          for VPN in $AUTOSTART; do
            if test "x$VPN" = "x$NAME" ; then
              AUTOVPN=1
            fi
          done
        fi
      fi
      if test "x$AUTOVPN" = "x1" ; then
        # If it is autostarted, then it contributes to global status
        status_of_proc -p /var/run/openvpn.${NAME}.pid openvpn "VPN '${NAME}'" || GLOBAL_STATUS=1
      else
        status_of_proc -p /var/run/openvpn.${NAME}.pid openvpn "VPN '${NAME}' (non autostarted)" || true
      fi
    done
  else
    # We just want status for specified VPNs.
    # Returns success if all specified VPNs are defined and running
    while shift ; do
      [ -z "$1" ] && break
      NAME=$1
      if test -e $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf ; then
        # Config exists
        status_of_proc -p /var/run/openvpn.${NAME}.pid openvpn "VPN '${NAME}'" || GLOBAL_STATUS=1
      else
        # Config does not exist
        log_warning_msg "VPN '$NAME': missing $CONFIG_DIR/$NAME.conf file !"
        GLOBAL_STATUS=1
      fi
    done
  fi
  exit $GLOBAL_STATUS
  ;;
*)
  echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|reload|restart|force-reload|cond-restart|soft-restart|status}" >&2
  exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0

# vim:set ai sts=2 sw=2 tw=0:
[20:46 gavin@raspbmc init.d] >
```

Comment: Can you post here your /etc/init.d/openvpn file?

Comment: Added `/etc/init.d/openvpn` as requested.  This is the default script that came with the package.

Comment: The easiest thing is to run the shell script yourself: as sudo, `/etc/init.d/openvpn`. This will write out any error it encounters. If you have any problem, pls reply.

Comment: Please read the question, I can run it with sudo but it doesn't start to boot. I only get an error starting it with `sudo service openvpn start`

Comment: What do you mean by *start it manually*? **1** openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/server.conf, **2** /etc/init.d/openvpn

Comment: As per the question. If I type `sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start` it works perfectly.

Comment: Heya, a bit late, but did you try `sudo systemctl start openvpn`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find good guidance here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206058/how-to-start-2fa-using-openvpn-with-systemd/206490#206490

TLDR: try # **systemctl start openvpn@name_of_config.service**